# How to Initiate a Specific Message to a User via a Telegram Bot Any Time After the User Starts the Bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, messaging

I am currently developing a Telegram bot and facing a specific challenge. My goal is to enable the bot to send a message I write, to the user immediately after they start the bot. I am not sure how to trigger the bot to send a message once the '/start' command is issued by the user.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. Created the bot using BotFather.
2. Set up a basic command handler for '/start'.
3. Able to receive messages from the user.

However, I am stuck at the point where I need the bot to initiate a conversation with the user right after they send the '/start' command and then send the message each time I tell the bot. I am looking for guidance on how to implement this functionality.

Can anyone provide insights or examples on how to achieve this? Specifically, I am interested in:

- Detecting the '/start' command from the user.
- Sending a response message from the bot to the user, which I write every time, immediately after the command is received.

Comment: Detecting /start should done with conversation handlers in a Telegram libraby. The second question I don't understand, replying on a command is very basic, but if you want the bot to say something you tell him he has to ask that to you first wich makes it a bit more complicated.